# VBA - Deleting duplicated in one string which are separated by semicolon

Tags: vba, excel, duplicates

I have got in one string like 800 adress emails. They are separated by semicolon. How should I do it to delete duplicates in that string?

Comment: To get started look into the [Split function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x627e5f(v=vs.90).aspx) and [Collections](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yb7y698k(v=vs.90).aspx) or [Dictonaries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251825.aspx).  The Split method will let you iterate over each email address in your string, and both Collections and Dictionaries can be used to only accept unique values.

Comment: text to cols based on `;` then unpivot the remove duplicates function.  all of these functions are readily searchable.

Comment: An attempt at some code would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Please update your question to show what you have already tried. It is very possible that your current code only needs a bit of tweaking.

Below is a more general way to accomplish what you're after, but like I said, there may be an easier way to fix your current code and you won't really learn by copying and pasting code.

```
Function RemoveDuplicates(rng as Range) As String
    Dim dict As Object
    Dim var As Variant, v As Variant

    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    var = Split(rng.Value,";")

    For each v in var
        If Not dict.Exists(v) Then
            dict.Add v, v
        End If
    Next v

    RemoveDuplicates = Join(dict.Keys, ";")
End Function
```