# Remove delimited duplicate values from within an Excel cell

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am trying to figure out how to remove duplicate values from with an Excel cell.  My columns have values separated by a semi-colon.  For example, in Column A I have these 3 rows with the values below.

```
3;5;6
2;2;4
9;5;12;12
```

What I am wanting to do in an adjacent column, call it column B, have a formula that returns:

```
3;5;6
2;4
9;5;12
```

What formula or function would I need to use to achieve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44390120/vba-deleting-duplicated-in-one-string-which-are-separated-by-semicolon

Answer (score 1):

The following formula can work with some limited conditions:

```
-using >= excel2019 version.
-all numbers in the strings > 0.
-all numbers in the string are integer.
-the maximum number in the string = 10^6
```

You can change `$1:$10` or `$1:$100`,..

```
C2=TEXTJOIN(";",,IF(1=FREQUENCY(IFERROR(MATCH(ROW($1:$10),--TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(B2,",",REPT(" ",LEN(B2))),(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A" & 1+ LEN(B2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B2,",",""))))-1)*LEN(B2)+1,LEN(B2))),0),1000),IFERROR(MATCH(ROW($1:$10),--TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(B2,",",REPT(" ",LEN(B2))),(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A" & 1+ LEN(B2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B2,",",""))))-1)*LEN(B2)+1,LEN(B2))),0),1000)),ROW($1:$10),""))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you have office 365 then you can try below formula and see if it helps you with your requirement.

`=TEXTJOIN(";",TRUE,(UNIQUE(FILTERXML("<t><d>"&SUBSTITUTE(A2,";","</d><d>")&"</d></t>","//d"))))`

For `FILTERXML` part, I will recommend going through below link on stackoverflow which creates array of individual elements from base string:

[Excel - Extract substring(s) from string using FILTERXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61837696/excel-extract-substrings-from-string-using-filterxml)

Rest of the structure is pretty standard which uses `UNIQUE` to get list of unique items and then we join them back together using `TEXTJOIN`.

Answer (score 1):

Another Office 365 or Excel 2019 formula solution

In B1, array (CSE) formula copied down :

```
=TEXTJOIN(";",1,IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(";"&ROW(A$1:A$9999)&";",";"&A1&";")),ROW(A$1:A$9999),""))
```

[image]

Comment: does this work with text as well or only numbers?  I did not realize that I do have some text strings as well, meaning 3;5;K; for example or 8;9;T

Comment: Short answer, No.